# Race condition while using async task with viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have a screen that uses viewpager which contains two fragments A and B and data in fragments are loaded using async task. My MainActivity class contains the following code in onCreate method:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
pager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
//Async task to get data from server and update the fragments
runGetDataTask(true);

/**
 * Adapter class for View pager
 */
public class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = {"A",
            "B"};

    public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

            case 0:
                iFragment = A.getInstance();
                if (Utility.IS_DEBUG)
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"A fragment created");
                return iFragment;
            case 1:
                dFragment = B.getInstance();
                if (Utility.IS_DEBUG)
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG,"B fragment created");
                return dFragment;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

The problem is that sometimes Async task completes its execution before fragments are initialized and when it try to access iFragment and dFragment to update data its has got from server I got nullpointerexception because fragments have not been initialized.

But this happens sometimes, I don't know what am I doing wrong here. Could someone please help me fix this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think a possibile workaround is to make sure that the ViewPager is initialised after the AsyncTask completes the its job. This can be achieved by creating a listener like:

```
public interface DataListener{
  public void onDataReceived();
}
```

and provide it to the AsyncTask (your activity must implement this interface). When the AsyncTask completes its work, then the listener is called and the control will be transferred back to the Activity that can initialise the UI.

Comment: @user818455 did it help?

Comment: I still don't understand how your solution will solve my problem? which code will make sure that viewpager fragments have been initialized and not null?